# Could not install Gradle distribution during creation of gradle project in windows

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I am creating a new gradle project in STS. It shows a error message

```
Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-bin.zip'.

PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException
```

I tried deleting the gradle directory under c:....gradle\wrapper\dists\

Even after that it throws the same error message.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: This looks like a problem with the TLS certificate. Are you probably missing the needed root certificate?

Comment: @Henry   What TLS certificate do I need

Comment: The certificate of this site is signed by "Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3". You will need to trust this CA certificate.

Comment: @Henry, I didn't see about this certificate in any questions around.